# Stratified random sampling using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am modelling habitat suitability for nest locations and for this, I need to randomly select X (30) number of cells in a specific area, where 40% of them have nest presence using QGIS.

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: I have tried using vector - research tools, but I can't find an option that is refined enough to be that specific. I have also manually created a column in the grid/cell attribute table that defines presence as 1 and absence as 0 but not sure how I can link this to a stratified random sample.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.